# UDP server/client using Qt

Tags: android, c++, qt, sockets

I'm trying to create an android application that sends a simple string from one device to another using UDP communication.(Socket/Client). I have no experience in socket programming only in C++. I am searching through the internet and i can't find any proper answer using QUDPsocket. I only see people not getting it right. I dont have any clue how to get this to work. For example, i quote a piece of quick code i wrote which in android it crashes, can this work? Any help would be appreciated very much. (Also i dont know if i can use the call like that in Qt)

```
void ClientDialog::sendDatagram()
{
    QByteArray datagram = "ThisMessage";

    QHostAddress mybroadcastaddress = QHostAddress("192.168.1.255");

    udpSocket->writeDatagram(datagram.data(),datagram.size(),mybroadcastaddress,45454);
}

void ClientDialog::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    sendDatagram();
}
```

Comment: What is 'udpSocket' and where is it created?

Comment: udpSocket is inside the header file. It is a pointer defined as, QUdpSocket *udpSocket

Comment: Show the code you wrote to create the `udpSocket`

Comment: Instead of `udpSocket  = new QUdpSocket(this);` i wrote in the header file `QUdpSocket *udpSocket;` there is no problem in that anyway, i think it's the same thing. I believe there is lack of code, importand code.

Comment: There seems to be a lack of udpSocket constructor, important udpSocket constructor.

Comment: `QUdpSocket *udpSocket;` is not the same thing as `udpSocket = new QUdpSocket(this);`. The first one is a declaration, the second one is an initialization.

Comment: There is insufficient amount of code shown to diagnose this issue. The code you show is correct. The incorrect part is not in your question, making your question off-topic until that is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok , so the answer was to just initialize the udpSocket. Using wireshark i saw that it sends the packets successfully :) (I thought it was too simple to be true :P ) Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

If writeDatagram fail, it only return -1 but not crash. One highly suspicious root cause is the nullptr pointer. As Martin said, please check the construction of udpSocket and make it valid pointer first.